# How to scale t-bond yield movements on a chart to visualize its relative impact to the pricing of other assets?

Tags: fixed-income, capm, bond-yields, quantitative

How does one scale bond yields on a chart to visualize its relative impact to asset valuations? I.e., so that the risk-free rate moving from 1->2% shows as a much larger movement than 11->12%.

For instance, assuming stocks have a constant equity risk premium and EPS, the risk-free rate moving from 1%->2% impacts CAPM more than 11%->12%. How do I scale yield movements to show the relative impact to valuations with those assumptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bonds, it is suggested that an $x$ ppt increase in the relevant interest rate will result in approximately $y$ percent decline in the valuation of a bond with a duration of $n$ years such that $y = nx$.

In example, if a bond has a duration of 5 years and the interest rate most applicable to the bond, such as the interest rate for similar bonds, increases by 2 ppt (for example 1% to 3%), the bond's price is expected to decline by 10% (=5*2%).

You may use this formula to estimate the potential rough impact of interest rate changes on a certain asset class other than a fixed income instrument by guestimating the rough average duration of the assets in the respective class.

Note that duration and maturity are not necessarily the same. There are many good sources on the internet but I reckon you can start with the "[Duration Definition](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/duration.asp)" article from investopedia.com.

Of course, this is all pretty rough and dirty and may work somewhat better for certain asset classes than the others because there is usually more than one factor that drives the valuation of an asset class. In addition, both the relations between these factors and the respective asset class as well as the factors themselves, such as the average duration of the asset class, may change over time.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, thank you. My issue was accounting for the convexity adjustment when modeling the expected impact to other assets. I *think* the easiest way to account for this is to simply use % change in bond price instead of change in yield since it has the convexity built in.